# How to add views into layout from list with delay

Tags: android

I have my custom view(CellView) stored in ArrayList and want to show items one-by-one with delay.

```
        Timer timing = new Timer();
        for (final CellView view : cellList) {

            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            timing.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    layout.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            layout.addView(view);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 500);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to show one by one while keeping the other or you want to replace one with another??

Comment: I want to show one by one while keeping other

Comment: Every cell already has coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show items set their visibility to invisible or gone initially and then set their visibility to visible with

```
  view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
   }, 500);
```

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is I can't add view inside of loop.

Comment: The problem with adding a list of my custom views was that I used LinearLayout instead of Relative and it seemed to me that the problem was with adding it in loop. So, I used your method after that. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to do it, but it sorted my problem when i needed to append text to scroll view every 0.5 seconds

```
import android.os.Handler;

TextView myView;


Handler handler = new Handler();

// BLOCK BEGIN
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myView.append("Whatever you want 1");

            }
        }, 500);

// BLOCK END
// BLOCK BEGIN
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myView.append("Whatever you want 2");

            }
        }, 1000);

// BLOCK END
```

I have just added new "BLOCK" for every ittem that i need to append over time..